# flush linux OS serial buffer

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-11.04

I have a serial program connecting to two devices via two different ports. Whenever I read, of course I have a local buffer with allocated statically with size of packet I am willing to read from serial. My boss, however, noted that storing packets to this local buffer will not be safe, rather he advised to check if I can flush linux OS buffer every time I read from serial. what is your opinion? and how can I do that programatically in ubuntu ?

I think this problem gets solved, if I add TCSAFLUSH to the tcsetattr function. this makes it flush the buffer after all data has been written to serial. this happens just before the next read. hopefully if I usleep() for some time ;)
what if your opinion?

Comment: The TTY is usually managed as a regular file, you can fflush(). Therefore flushing makes sense when writing. When reading simply consume all bytes.

Comment: I am telling this because the connection may be noisy. so, just using fflush() after a write() would take of it, wouldn't it?

Comment: Long time since I've played with RS232 in C, actually it would flush all remaining bytes on the TTY.

Comment: fflush is for standard library. I am looking for the system call.

Comment: I think this problem gets solved, if I add TCSAFLUSH to the tcsetattr function\

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `tcdrain(fd)` or the `tcsetattr()` option `TCSADRAIN`.

`TCSAFLUSH` (and `tcflush()`) empty the buffer by discarding the data - `tcdrain()` waits (blocking) until all data has been sent from the buffer:

> **Line control**
>
> ...
>
> tcdrain()  waits  until all output written to the object referred to by fd has been transmitted.
>
> -- man termios

I use the function just before resetting the port options to what they were before I changed them and close the port:

```
void SerialPort::close() {
    if (_fd > -1) {
        tcdrain(_fd);
        ioctl(_fd, TCSETS2, &_savedOptions);
        ::close(_fd);
    }
    _fd = -1;
}
```